# PostGIS2 have automatic BBOX indexing?

Tags: postgis-2.0

I need to compare millions of geometries by the `&&` operator (BBOX).

When `CREATE TABLE` see `geometry` type on PostGIS2, it do also something like `INDEX ON t USING GIST(g)`? or **I need to express, always, the `CREATE INDEX` in (or after) my `CREATE TABLE`?**

If it is automatic, it is for any field name (or only for "geom")?

---

PS: (if no index is automatically crated)  when I use `ST_DWithin(A,B)` PostGIS generate a temporary index?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, database indexes are *not* created by default.

From [Building Indexes](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idp33226976) of the PostGIS manual,

```
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometryfield] );
```

is required to create a spatial index. It must be based on a geometry column, though what you call that column is up to you.

From [CREATE INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) of the PostgreSQL manual,

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] [ name ] ON table [ USING method ]
( { column | ( expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [ ASC | DESC ] [ NULLS { FIRST | LAST } ] [, ...] )
[ WITH ( storage_parameter = value [, ... ] ) ]
[ TABLESPACE tablespace ]
[ WHERE predicate ]
```

is required for creating an "ordinary" (*non*-spatial) index on a particular column.

You may create more than one index for any table. A rough guide as to when it would help is to look at the queries you use, see what columns are part of the `WHERE` clauses, and consider indexing those columns.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this question a little while back.  sped up my code significantly on points, but the same concept applies to other geometry types.  you just have to be careful using it with things other than points for unexpected results.  Basically, you use the <-> command on geometries instead of st_dwithin.  Have a look at this tutorial, it sounds like this is what you need.

http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

Comment: update, use the && operator in your where statement.  <-> is for calculating distance between BBOX centers.  And as @martin f said, you have to create the index every time.

Answer (score 0):

No. I exampled the table creation process using the new postgis geometry column constructor like on example below:

> CREATE TABLE pois_ny(gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY    , poi_name text, cat
>   varchar(20)    , geom geometry(POINT,4326) );

It does create a table with a constrained column named geom which geometry type is POINT and srid 4326. Trying to insert a different geometry will cause a failure.

> insert into pois_ny ( poi_name, geom ) values ( 'Teste point',
>   st_makePoint( 0, 0 ) )

The above fails since srid is 0.

But it did not created a spatial index.

Comment: Thanks, good example. What occurs with `INSERT INTO pois_ny ( poi_name, geom ) values  ( 'A', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-70, 40),4326) ) , ( 'B', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1, 42.3),4326) ), ( 'C', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-70, 40),4326) ) ;`  when comparing `A&&B OR A&&C`, it is a "optimized comparison", or no BBOX-index is used?

Comment: The explain analyse reported sequencial scan on table. So, no bbox comparison was used. But the test table has few rows of data. Need generate a larger test table with about 5000 rows to see some benefits of index.

Comment: I'd like to point out that while you can create a table the way you have above, the prefered best practice is to create a general table, and use the ```sql addGeometryColumn``` function to add a geometry column, which not only forces you to specify srid, dimensions, and type, but also registers the column with postgis in the geometry columns view in the public schema.

Comment: What I understood from manual, that this would be the preferred way with postgis2. The srid is explicit on table, the type is given with the Point parameter. Also, the dimension is declared since POINT is a 2D type. POINTZ would be the 3d type as example. It too did the registration on geometry columns view. All in a small compact two value expression.